# CentOS 6.5 mkdir invalid argument

Tags: linux, centos, mkdir, ext4

server is running on centOS6.5 with ext4 file system

We have a problem with create a new dir in specific folder (for eg. /var/www/html/img/) when we are trying use mkdir,cp,scp, from another server,create with winSCP, and php script it's type "mk dir cant create folder 'name' invalid argument

when we was trying create something "upper" (for eg. /var/www/html) everything was created correct

have somebody some idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: It's very unclear what you are trying to do and what the problem you are encountering.  Please check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In this case show the commands you execute and their result including things like directory ownership, permissions etc. (ls -ld etc.)

Comment: I was execute: "mkdir 25000" - for create folder with name "25000", then i was trying "cp 24999 25000" for copy old folder but with result invalid argument, then i was trying from another server use "scp 25000 root@server.com:/var/www/html/img/25000" with same result - invalid argument, i was loged as root and folder have 777 permision for me. Now we was trying to restart server, and its work for a while, but now its same error

Comment: Is 25000 a directory?  The `scp` used for transporting files, so you should use `scp -rf 25000/ root@server.com:/var/www/html/img/25000`. And the directory `root@server.com:/var/www/html/img/25000` which used for putting the files must exist.

Comment: yes 25000 is a directory, i was trying scp -rf and still same result and of course folder on another server (from was used scp)  is exist.

Comment: @PatrikHelia please update the question with this information.  It will become a lot easier to understand for others so you are much more likely to get an answer.  You should look at your question through the eyes of someone who does not know your system, does not know what you are trying to achieve and see if it is clear.